# Unattended Upgrades doesn't work anymore since Debian 10 to 11 upgrade

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

All seems to be correctly set up on my Debian 11 but I don't know why the unattended upgrade doesn't work any more since my upgrade to Debian 11.

While I perform an apt update, I found packages that needs to be upgraded:

```
7 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Here is my sources.list :

```
# #deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.2.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20191116-09:57]/ buster contrib main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.2.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20191116-09:57]/ buster contrib main

#deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
#deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

Output of my unattended upgrades in debug mode:

```
sudo unattended-upgrades --debug --dry-run
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: origin=Debian,codename=bullseye-updates, origin=Debian,codename=bullseye-proposed-updates, origin=Debian,codename=bullseye,label=Debian, origin=Debian,codename=bullseye,label=Debian-Security
Initial blacklist:
Initial whitelist (not strict):
Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.nodesource.com_node%5f16.x_dists_bullseye_main_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=,c=main,v=,o=Node Source,l=Node Source arch='amd64' site='deb.nodesource.com' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=1209 ID:14> with -32768 pin
Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en'  a=bullseye-backports,c=main,v=,o=Debian Backports,l=Debian Backports arch='' site='deb.debian.org' IndexType='Debian Translation Index' Size=377020 ID:13> with -32768 pin
Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=bullseye-backports,c=main,v=,o=Debian Backports,l=Debian Backports arch='amd64' site='deb.debian.org' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=656568 ID:12> with -32768 pin
Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bullseye-security_main_i18n_Translation-en'  a=stable-security,c=main,v=11,o=Debian,l=Debian-Security arch='' site='deb.debian.org' IndexType='Debian Translation Index' Size=187892 ID:9> with -32768 pin
Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bullseye-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=stable-security,c=main,v=11,o=Debian,l=Debian-Security arch='amd64' site='deb.debian.org' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=266792 ID:8> with -32768 pin
Applying pinning: PkgFilePin(id=14, priority=-32768)
Applying pin -32768 to package_file: <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.nodesource.com_node%5f16.x_dists_bullseye_main_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=,c=main,v=,o=Node Source,l=Node Source arch='amd64' site='deb.nodesource.com' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=1209 ID:14>
Applying pinning: PkgFilePin(id=13, priority=-32768)
Applying pin -32768 to package_file: <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en'  a=bullseye-backports,c=main,v=,o=Debian Backports,l=Debian Backports arch='' site='deb.debian.org' IndexType='Debian Translation Index' Size=377020 ID:13>
Applying pinning: PkgFilePin(id=12, priority=-32768)
Applying pin -32768 to package_file: <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=bullseye-backports,c=main,v=,o=Debian Backports,l=Debian Backports arch='amd64' site='deb.debian.org' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=656568 ID:12>
Applying pinning: PkgFilePin(id=9, priority=-32768)
Applying pin -32768 to package_file: <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bullseye-security_main_i18n_Translation-en'  a=stable-security,c=main,v=11,o=Debian,l=Debian-Security arch='' site='deb.debian.org' IndexType='Debian Translation Index' Size=187892 ID:9>
Applying pinning: PkgFilePin(id=8, priority=-32768)
Applying pin -32768 to package_file: <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bullseye-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=stable-security,c=main,v=11,o=Debian,l=Debian-Security arch='amd64' site='deb.debian.org' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=266792 ID:8>
Using (^linux-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^kfreebsd-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^gnumach-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^.*-modules-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^.*-kernel-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^linux-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^kfreebsd-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^gnumach-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^.*-modules-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^.*-kernel-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$) regexp to find kernel packages
Using (^linux-.*-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^linux-.*-5\.10\.0\-8$|^kfreebsd-.*-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^kfreebsd-.*-5\.10\.0\-8$|^gnumach-.*-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^gnumach-.*-5\.10\.0\-8$|^.*-modules-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^.*-modules-5\.10\.0\-8$|^.*-kernel-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^.*-kernel-5\.10\.0\-8$|^linux-.*-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^linux-.*-5\.10\.0\-8$|^kfreebsd-.*-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^kfreebsd-.*-5\.10\.0\-8$|^gnumach-.*-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^gnumach-.*-5\.10\.0\-8$|^.*-modules-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^.*-modules-5\.10\.0\-8$|^.*-kernel-5\.10\.0\-8\-amd64$|^.*-kernel-5\.10\.0\-8$) regexp to find running kernel packages
Checking: gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'stable-security' origin:'Debian' label:'Debian-Security' site:'deb.debian.org' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0=2.32.3-1
Checking: gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'stable-security' origin:'Debian' label:'Debian-Security' site:'deb.debian.org' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: gir1.2-webkit2-4.0=2.32.3-1
Checking: libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'stable-security' origin:'Debian' label:'Debian-Security' site:'deb.debian.org' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18=2.32.3-1
Checking: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'stable-security' origin:'Debian' label:'Debian-Security' site:'deb.debian.org' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37=2.32.3-1
Checking: linux-image-5.10.0-8-amd64 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'stable-security' origin:'Debian' label:'Debian-Security' site:'deb.debian.org' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: linux-image-5.10.0-8-amd64=5.10.46-4
Checking: linux-image-amd64 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'stable-security' origin:'Debian' label:'Debian-Security' site:'deb.debian.org' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: linux-image-amd64=5.10.46-4
Checking: nodejs ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'' origin:'Node Source' label:'Node Source' site:'deb.nodesource.com' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: nodejs=16.9.1-deb-1nodesource1
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded:
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
fetch.run() result: 0
Packages blacklist due to conffile prompts: []
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
The list of kept packages can't be calculated in dry-run mode.
```

My config file for unattended upgrades:

```
// Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern controls which packages are
// upgraded.
//
// Lines below have the format format is "keyword=value,...".  A
// package will be upgraded only if the values in its metadata match
// all the supplied keywords in a line.  (In other words, omitted
// keywords are wild cards.) The keywords originate from the Release
// file, but several aliases are accepted.  The accepted keywords are:
//   a,archive,suite (eg, "stable")
//   c,component     (eg, "main", "contrib", "non-free")
//   l,label         (eg, "Debian", "Debian-Security")
//   o,origin        (eg, "Debian", "Unofficial Multimedia Packages")
//   n,codename      (eg, "jessie", "jessie-updates")
//     site          (eg, "http.debian.net")
// The available values on the system are printed by the command
// "apt-cache policy", and can be debugged by running
// "unattended-upgrades -d" and looking at the log file.
//
// Within lines unattended-upgrades allows 2 macros whose values are
// derived from /etc/debian_version:
//   ${distro_id}            Installed origin.
//   ${distro_codename}      Installed codename (eg, "buster")
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        // Codename based matching:
        // This will follow the migration of a release through different
        // archives (e.g. from testing to stable and later oldstable).
        // Software will be the latest available for the named release,
        // but the Debian release itself will not be automatically upgraded.
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-updates";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-proposed-updates";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";

        // Archive or Suite based matching:
        // Note that this will silently match a different release after
        // migration to the specified archive (e.g. testing becomes the
        // new stable).
//     "o=Debian,a=stable";
//     "o=Debian,a=stable-updates";
//     "o=Debian,a=proposed-updates";
//     "o=Debian Backports,a=${distro_codename}-backports,l=Debian Backports";
};

// Python regular expressions, matching packages to exclude from upgrading
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    // The following matches all packages starting with linux-
//  "linux-";

    // Use $ to explicitely define the end of a package name. Without
    // the $, "libc6" would match all of them.
//  "libc6$";
//  "libc6-dev$";
//  "libc6-i686$";

    // Special characters need escaping
//  "libstdc\+\+6$";

    // The following matches packages like xen-system-amd64, xen-utils-4.1,
    // xenstore-utils and libxenstore3.0
//  "(lib)?xen(store)?";

    // For more information about Python regular expressions, see
    // https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
};

// This option allows you to control if on a unclean dpkg exit
// unattended-upgrades will automatically run 
//   dpkg --force-confold --configure -a
// The default is true, to ensure updates keep getting installed
//Unattended-Upgrade::AutoFixInterruptedDpkg "true";

// Split the upgrade into the smallest possible chunks so that
// they can be interrupted with SIGTERM. This makes the upgrade
// a bit slower but it has the benefit that shutdown while a upgrade
// is running is possible (with a small delay)
//Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";

// Install all updates when the machine is shutting down
// instead of doing it in the background while the machine is running.
// This will (obviously) make shutdown slower.
// Unattended-upgrades increases logind's InhibitDelayMaxSec to 30s.
// This allows more time for unattended-upgrades to shut down gracefully
// or even install a few packages in InstallOnShutdown mode, but is still a
// big step back from the 30 minutes allowed for InstallOnShutdown previously.
// Users enabling InstallOnShutdown mode are advised to increase
// InhibitDelayMaxSec even further, possibly to 30 minutes.
//Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "false";

// Send email to this address for problems or packages upgrades
// If empty or unset then no email is sent, make sure that you
// have a working mail setup on your system. A package that provides
// 'mailx' must be installed. E.g. "user@example.com"
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "myemail@myemail.com";

// Set this value to "true" to get emails only on errors. Default
// is to always send a mail if Unattended-Upgrade::Mail is set
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "false";

// Remove unused automatically installed kernel-related packages
// (kernel images, kernel headers and kernel version locked tools).
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";

// Do automatic removal of newly unused dependencies after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-New-Unused-Dependencies "true";

// Do automatic removal of unused packages after the upgrade
// (equivalent to apt-get autoremove)
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";

// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if
//  the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";

// Automatically reboot even if there are users currently logged in
// when Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot is set to true
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-WithUsers "false";

// If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
// time instead of immediately
//  Default: "now"
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";

// Use apt bandwidth limit feature, this example limits the download
// speed to 70kb/sec
//Acquire::http::Dl-Limit "70";

// Enable logging to syslog. Default is False
// Unattended-Upgrade::SyslogEnable "false";

// Specify syslog facility. Default is daemon
// Unattended-Upgrade::SyslogFacility "daemon";

// Download and install upgrades only on AC power
// (i.e. skip or gracefully stop updates on battery)
// Unattended-Upgrade::OnlyOnACPower "true";

// Download and install upgrades only on non-metered connection
// (i.e. skip or gracefully stop updates on a metered connection)
// Unattended-Upgrade::Skip-Updates-On-Metered-Connections "true";

// Verbose logging
Unattended-Upgrade::Verbose "true";

// Print debugging information both in unattended-upgrades and
// in unattended-upgrade-shutdown
Unattended-Upgrade::Debug "true";
```

The 20auto-upgrades is as well correctly customized:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

The service works correctly from what I see:

```
    sudo systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service
    ●  unattended-upgrades.service - Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-10-04 13:12:12 CEST; 27s ago
       Docs: man:unattended-upgrade(8)
   Main PID: 561 (unattended-upgr)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 19156)
     Memory: 20.8M
        CPU: 213ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/unattended-upgrades.service
             └─561 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal

Oct 04 13:12:12 WIPMagentoLocal systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
```

Could you please help me to make it work again? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For security updates in Debian 11, you need to [change the “Debian-Security” line in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/commit/86ee50f03bb14ecfacf18cd1ce51208c6521e755#diff-d734c6acfa60e9d620f4afb885d0148e51c68424e9ed2ea28b18cee4dd5b8773) to

```
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-security,label=Debian-Security";
```

(note [the addition of `-security`](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#security-archive)).